# AWS CDK - StepFunction - Modify input before passing to the next step

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have a 3 step state machine for a step function.

InputStep -> ExecuteSparkJob -> OutputLambda

ExecuteSparkJob is a glue task. Since it cannot pass its output to the step function, it writes it output to an S3 bucket. OutputLambda reads it from there and passes it on to the step function.

The idea of `InputStep` is simply to define a common S3 URI that the following steps can use.

Below is the code I have for the Input Step.

```js
const op1 = Data.stringAt("$.op1");
const op2 = Data.stringAt("$.op2");

const inputTask = new Pass(this, "Input Step", {
    result: Result.fromString(this.getURI(op1, op2)),
    resultPath: "$.s3path"
});

getURI(op1: string, op2: string): string {
    return op1.concat("/").concat(op2).concat("/").concat("response");
}
```

However, the string manipulation that I am doing in `getURI` is not working. The values in `inputTask.result` are not being substituted by the value in `Path`.

This is the input and output to the `Input Step`

```json
{
  "op1": "test1",
  "op2": "test2"
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "op1": "test1",
  "op2": "test2"
  "responsePath": "$.op1/$.op2/response"
}
```

Is it possible to do some string manipulations using parameters in the `Path` in Step Function definition? If yes, what am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one or more `EvaluateExpression` Tasks - it's still a bit clunky.

You can find examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-tasks-readme.html#evaluate-expression).

API doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-stepfunctions-tasks.EvaluateExpression.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `Pass` state's `Parameters` field [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions-states) the intrinsic functions and substitutions you need to do this natively, without a Lambda task.  The `Result` field doesn't.

Compose a string from the execution inputs with the [Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-generic) intrinsic function:

```js
const inputTask = new Pass(this, "Input Step", {
  parameters: {
    path: JsonPath.format(
      "{}/{}/response",
      JsonPath.stringAt("$.op1"),
      JsonPath.stringAt("$.op2")
    ),
  },
  outputPath: "$.s3",
});
```

The resulting string value `test1/test2/response` will be output to  `$.s3.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Lambda function instead of a Pass state to build the string.

Step Functions doesn't currently support string concatenation with reference paths. The `Result` field of a Pass state doesn't allow reference paths either. It has to be static value.

Comment: Seems a little excessive to build a lambda just to concatenate a string..

Comment: I could not find another way. I forgot to update the question but I did end up implementing a lambda to achieve this. I will update with my exact implementation soon.